# How do you use a TF-IDF matrix to score text similarity?

Tags: natural-language, text-mining, tf-idf

I'm trying to match strings of words with a website which has bulletpoints from all of the URL's I'm interested in whose text is most similar to it. The way I thought of doing it is to get all of the documents from each bulletpoint into one corpus per website that I want to match a string of words with, discarding stop words and lemmatizing everything. Then, for each string of text, I create a TF-IDF sparse matrix, with each row the text from a single bulletpoint from a single website, so that the matrix contains all the text from the bulletpoints from all the websites, as well as a row for the string of words I want to match.

How should I then decide which row my string of words is most similar to? Should I get the cosine similarity of every row with my string of words row and just take whatever one has the highest cosine similarity (I'll have a way of identifying the row with the website it was scrapped from)? Or is there an actual formalized way to go about this once I have my sparse matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If your string of words is not weighted (no hierarchy of most important to least important word), tf-idf-weighting and desparsing is not really necessary. You are only interested in the words in your string, so all other words may be disregarded.

Just compose a `document x relevant terms` tf-matrix. Then, divide each column (the count for each word) by the maximal number of times this word occurred, thereby normalizing each word count to a 0 (did not occur) to 1 (occurred most frequently) score. By summing up the scores for each document, you get the highest score for the most relevant document.